# Full github issue and project board integration for IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: github, intellij-idea, issue-tracking

I recently found out that apart from just simply pushing/pulling from a github repo from within IntelliJ IDEA, you can also create pull requests and create tasks and change lists based on issues on the github repo (even with git-flow integration).

Now I am wondering: how far does the github integration go within IntelliJ?

- Is it possible to create new issues from within IntelliJ?
- Is it possible to view your project board to see which issues are in 
  progress, being reviewed or done?
- Is it possible to automatically move an issue card on the board to in progress when the branch gets created?

(If not, who would be willing to extend the github plugin to include these features? :P)